# About saturated sets

Tags: general-topology

[image]

The above paragraph claims that $C=p^{-1}(D)$ for some $D\subset Y$. I think $D=\{y\in Y| p^{-1}(y)\cap C\ne \emptyset\}$. Is this correct? Even if so, I can't prove it.

Is the converse true? That is, if $C$ is saturated, then $C=p^{-1}(D)$. I think I managed to prove one inclusion. If $y\in D$, then I must prove that $p^{-1}(y)\in C$. Let $x\in p^{-1}(y)$. Then $p(x)=y\in D$ and so $x=p^{-1}(y)$. Since $y\in D$, $x\cap C\ne \emptyset$, and since $C$ is saturated, $x\in C$. This proves $p^{-1}(D)\subset C$

Comment: There may be many sets $D$ such that $p^{-1}(D) = C$.  One such set is $D = \{ y \in Y : p^{-1}(y) \cap C \neq \emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $C$ is saturated. I claim that $p^{-1}[p[C]] = C$ and so $C$ is the pre-image of a subset of $Y$, as claimed (so we can take $D = p[C]$).

Note that by definition we always have $p^{-1}[p[C]] \supseteq C$, because $c \in C$ implies $p(c) \in p[C]$ and so $c \in p^{-1}[p[C]]$. Now suppose that $x \in p^{-1}[p[C]]$. This means that $p(x) \in p[C]$ or there is a $c \in C$ such that $p(c) = p(x)$.
So $C$ intersects $p^{-1}[\{p(x)\}$ and by being saturated, $p^{-1}[\{p(x)\}] \subseteq C$ ($C$ contains every fibre it intersects). And in particular, $x \in p^{-1}[\{p(x)\}] \subseteq C$, showing the reverse inclusion.

Reversely it's easy to check that $C = p^{-1}[D]$ is indeed always a saturated subset of $X$.

Comment: Did you mean $x\in p^{-1}[\{p(x)\}]\subseteq C$? Also, the text claims that a set $C\subset X$ is saturated if it equals the preimage of a set in $Y$. Rephrasing, if a set $C$ equals $f^{-1}(D)$ for some $D\subset Y$, then $C$ is called saturated. You are saying $D=p(C)$. But how can we take $p(C)$ if $C$ is being defined, we can't take the image of $C$ until it has been defined.

Comment: @user531587 yes to the first, I edited this typo. $C$ is a given subset of $X$ so of course we can take its image.

Comment: @user531587 what you’re in fact proving: for any subset $C$ of $X$, $C$ is saturated (in the fibre sense) iff $C$ can be written as $p^{-1}[D]$ for some subset $D$ of $Y$. You’re not defining $C$ but a property of sets that $C$ can have.

Comment: Is the converse implication a particular case of the statement that says that $p^{-1}[D]$ is saturated for any $D$? So in particular it's saturated for $D=p[C]$?

Comment: @user531587 Sure.